# WooCommerce my account custom tab with custom content

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

please let me know how to add multiple custom menu tab by endpoint with the results who getting from db? the below code works but showing same content for all my custom menu items, while there are 3 result from database as you see in the picture
[image]

```html
function pa_custom_endpoint_keys() {
    global $wpdb;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $pao  = $wpdb->prefix . 'pao';
    $results=$wpdb->get_results("select * from $pao");
        $endpointsdata =array();
        foreach($results as $row){
        $endpointsdata[$row->pao_name] = $row->pao_value;
        }
        return $endpointsdata;
}

add_action( 'init', 'pa_custom_endpoint' );
function pa_custom_endpoint() {
    foreach(pa_custom_endpoint_keys() as $endpointkey=>$endpointlable){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( $endpointkey, EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    }
}
//
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'pa_custom_endpoint_query_vars', 0 );
function pa_custom_endpoint_query_vars( $vars ) {
    foreach(pa_custom_endpoint_keys() as $endpointkey=>$endpointlable){
    $vars[] = $endpointkey;
    }
    return $vars;
}
//
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'pa_custom_endpoint_link_my_account' );
function pa_custom_endpoint_link_my_account( $items ) {
    foreach(pa_custom_endpoint_keys() as $endpointkey=>$endpointlable){
    $items[$endpointkey] = $endpointlable;
    }
    return $items;
}
//
function pa_custom_endpoint_content() {
        foreach(pa_custom_endpoint_keys() as $endpointkey=>$endpointlable):
        endforeach;
        echo $endpointlable;
}
    foreach(pa_custom_endpoint_keys() as $endpointkey=>$endpointlable){
$activetabendpoint=$endpointkey;
$underline="_";
$endpoint="endpoint";
$activeendpointcontenthook="woocommerce_account_$activetabendpoint$underline$endpoint";
add_action( $activeendpointcontenthook, 'pa_custom_endpoint_content');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function add_custom_menu_items( $items, $args ) {
if ( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) { // Replace 'primary' with the name of your menu location
$endpoint_url = 'https://example.com/your-endpoint';
$data = wp_remote_get( $endpoint_url );
$data = json_decode( $data['body'], true );

foreach ( $data as $item ) {
$menu_item = '<li class="menu-item">';
$menu_item .= '<a href="' . esc_attr( $item['url'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $item['name'] ) . '</a>';
$menu_item .= '</li>';
$items .= $menu_item;
}
}

return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_custom_menu_items', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your kindly reply @mona.
That's exactly solution im looking for, a way to get the current endpoint to use it while getting the tab content from the database. for ex:
$tab_x_content=$wpdb->get_results("select * from $pao WHERE endpint=$current_entpoint_that_user_in_or_active endpoint");